# Bug in sytaxis in MysqlServer : the foreign key refers to an invalid table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I spent hours to find the bug on my script. MysqlServer shows me the error: the foreign key refers to an invalid table. Some help? Thanks

--SCRIPT_MER_MOCHILAS ENTIDADES FUERTES:MODELO, DUEÑO,MOCHILA, MATERIAL, DISEÑO, COLOR, TIPO_MOCHILA, MARCA.ENTIDADES DEBILES: DU_MO, CO_DI, MA_DI --

CREATE TABLE TAB_DUENO
(
ID_DUENO INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1), 
 DUENO VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
 NOMBRE VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
 APELLIDOP VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
 APELLIDOM VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE CAT_MODELO
(
ID_MODELO INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1), 
 MODELO VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
)
CREATE TABLE TAB_MOCHILA
(
ID_MOCHILA INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1), 
 MOCHILA VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_MODELO_MOCHILA
FOREIGN KEY (ID_MODELO)REFERENCES CAT_MODELO(ID_MODELO),
CONSTRAINT FK_DISENO_MOCHILA
FOREIGN KEY (ID_DISEÑO)REFERENCES CAT_DISENO(ID_DISENO),
CONSTRAINT FK_TIPOMOCHILA_MOCHILA
FOREIGN KEY (ID_TIPOMOCHILA)REFERENCES CAT_TIPOMOCHILA(ID_TIPOMOCHILA),
CONSTRAINT FK_MARCA_MOCHILA
FOREIGN KEY (ID_MARCA)REFERENCES CAT_MARCA(ID_MARCA),
)
CREATE TABLE CAT_MATERIAL
(
ID_MATERIAL INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
 MATERIAL VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL 
)
CREATE TABLE CAT_COLOR
(
ID_COLOR INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
 COLOR VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL 
)
CREATE TABLE CAT_TIPOMOCHILA
(
ID_TIPOMOCHILA INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1), 
 TIPOMOCHILA VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
)
CREATE TABLE CAT_DISEÑO 
(
ID_DISEÑO INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1), 
 DISEÑO VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
)
CREATE TABLE CAT_MARCA
(
ID_MARCA INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1), 
 MARCA VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
)
--AHORA VAN LAS ENTIDADES DEBILES//

CREATE TABLE DUENO_MOCHILA
(
ID_DUENOMOCHILA INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1), 
 DUENOMOCHILA VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_DUEÑO_DUENOMOCHILA
FOREIGN KEY (ID_DUEÑO)REFERENCES CAT_DUENO(ID_DUENO),
CONSTRAINT FK_MOCHILA_DUENOMOCHILA
FOREIGN KEY (ID_MOCHILA)REFERENCES CAT_MOCHILA(ID_MOCHILA),
)

CREATE TABLE COLORDISENO
(
ID_COLORDISENO INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1), 
 COLORDISENO VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_COLOR_COLORDISEÑO
FOREIGN KEY (ID_COLOR)REFERENCES CAT_COLOR(ID_COLOR),
CONSTRAINT FK_DISENO_COLORDISEÑO
FOREIGN KEY (ID_DISENO)REFERENCES CAT_DISENO(ID_DISENO),
)
CREATE TABLE MATERIALDISENO
(
ID_MATERIALDISENO INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1), 
 MATERIALDISENO VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_MATERIAL_MATERIALDISENO
FOREIGN KEY (ID_MATERIAL)REFERENCES CAT_MATERIAL(ID_MATERIAL),
CONSTRAINT FK_DISENO_MATERIALDISENO
FOREIGN KEY (ID_DISENO)REFERENCES CAT_DISENO(ID_DISENO),
)

Comment: Please take a few moments and format your code.  Add four or more spaces to each line containing code.

Comment: None of these create statements are terminated with a semi-colon (;) and you are using an identity clause - this suggest to me that you are using sqlserver or trying to convert from sqlserver to mysql can you clarify please.

Answer (score 0):

You have not understood foreign keys the syntax is correct but the italicised bit isn't CONSTRAINT FK_MODELO_MOCHILA FOREIGN KEY (***ID_MODELO***)REFERENCES CAT_MODELO(ID_MODELO) this column should be the name of the field in TAB_MOCHILA that you want to relate to CAT_MODELO(ID_MODELO) .